# Page to learn the advanced uses of classes and vectors of classes

Tags: c++, class, vector

I want to learn the advanced uses of vectors with classes, e.g. defining a vector of a class type with a pointer, advanced use of this pointer etc.

So please can anyone suggest me a good website for a video tutorial for this thing?

Comment: [this book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Accelerated-Practical-Programming-Example-Depth/dp/020170353X) contains a chapter demonstrating how to build a class that mimics the behaviour of `std::vector`.

Comment: Advance use of a `std::vector`?  It's a container.  You could make a matrix using `std::vector` if that is more advanced.  Please clarify your meaning of "advanced".

Comment: "Advanced" mean to say the use of pointers with vector and classes. Vectors of type class along with pointers. Object pointers etc.